# Enthalpy of steam vs specific heat

Tags: thermodynamics

I have a question about the relation between enthalpy and the specific heat of water.

If we look in the [property tables](https://eclass.upatras.gr/modules/document/file.php/MECH1206/CENGEL_%20PROPERTY%20Tables%206%20NEW-SIappendix1.pdf) (Page 890) at let's say 20 degC, the properties of water are:

- $P_{sat} = 2.34 kPa$,
- $h_{f} = 83.915 kJ/kg$
- $h_{g} = 2537.4 kJ/kg$
- $Cp = 4.18 kJ/kg$

And if we say that the saturated liquid behaves like a incompressible liquid, the following expression applies:

$h_f = Cp_L T = 4.18 \cdot 20 = 83.6 kJ/kg$ which is similar to the one in the table.

But if we assume that the saturated vapor behaves as an ideal gas, this should apply:

$h_g = Cp_G T = 4.18 \cdot (20 + 273) = 1224 kJ/kg$, which is far from the value of $h_g$ from the table.

And okay, steam has a different specific heat ($C_{p,steam} = 1.87$ - Table A-2).
Then

$h_g = Cp_G T = 1.87 \cdot (20 + 273) = 547 kJ/kg$

It still doesn't match! More than that, the value is very far.

I know that ideal gas is a pretty rough approximation, but the pressure and temperature are far from the critical point, so the error should not be that high. What am I doing wrong?

Paul

Comment: You are not taking into account the heat of vaporizaton.  $h_g=h_f+\Delta h_v$

Comment: $Delta h_v$ is the energy necessary to break to bonds, right? By definition it looks like that latent energy will stay in the gas (steam)... Is that right?

Comment: Sure, since, when it's vaporized, there's no liquid left.  For purposes of this table, there is a datum state at which u is taken to be equal to zero:  liquid water at 0 C at either 1 atm or the equilibrium vapor pressure, depending on the table (probably the latter).  Everything else is referenced to this state.

Comment: Okay. Then it makes sense... Thank you, Chester. You are always the first to answer and help me learn :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. So thanks to Chester Miller, I have managed to answer the question.

So to get $h_g$ for steam, one can use:

$h_g = Cp_L T + h_{fg} = 4.18 \cdot 20 + 2453 = 2536.6 kJ/kg $

Where $h_{fg}$ is taken from that link.